# Should the Observing/Subscribing be done on the View or Presenter?

Tags: android, rx-java, mvp

For example if there's an activity with a button(View). When this is pressed, it calls a Presenter method, this method gets an observable from a service(Model) - which could take a long time to reply with results.

Should the subscriber for these results be kept on the Presenter? Then depending on the results, the Presenter would call the relevant View's actions?

Or should the subscriber be on the View? As I've been seeing in these other rx android example projects. In which case the activity/fragment would be calling other View or Presenter methods depending on the subscription's results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main goal of MVP pattern is to decouple the data access mechanism from view(activities, fragments). To make an application to be easily extensible and maintainable we need to define well separated layers.

If you return you subscriber on the view then it will break the MVP pattern. You should make your view as dumb as possible. So you should subscribe on presenter layer and let the presenter layer decide what should be the next step in the view. There might be some situation arise when different kinds of action might happen on the view. That logic should not be present on view.

**NB:This is just a suggestion. Make your view dumb. But you have to decide how much dumb you will make the view based on the action it performs. For an example there is a button whose click event pop up a yes/no kind of dialog. You should not call the presenter that the button clicked and let it tell the view to open a dialog.

But the situation you describe above you should use a presenter layer.

Answer (score 1):

Presenter should do all the logic and heavy lifting while view is simple as possible. It only registers user input and, after all is done, shows the results.

> Should the subscriber for these results be kept on the Presenter? Then
>   depending on the results, the Presenter would call the relevant View's
>   actions?

Yes, this is correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to always keep subscription on Presenter. If View is allowed to 'see' the Model, it should only interact with Model in some simple manner such as data binding and simple validation. Otherwise, View is dump, Presenter proceeds all business logic.

Passive View and Supervising Controller are two variants of MVP for your references.

Please also checkout a new MVP framework for Android at http://robo-creative.github.io/mvp. Samples on there explains the difference between those variants. Have fun!